# Why does Fluorine-19 have a nuclear spin of 1/2?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, nuclear-physics, quantum-spin

According to the nuclear shell model, $^{19}F$ has one unpaired proton in the $6$-fold degenerate $1d_{5/2}$ state, which means the orbital angular momentum is $l = 2$ and the total angular momentum is $j = l+ \frac12 = 5/2$. If we follow the [rule highlighted by Lubos Motl](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/90763/76347) that nuclear states with higher $m_j$ are filled first, then the one unpaired proton goes in the $m_j = 5/2$ state predicting a nuclear spin of $5/2$. However, we know that $^{19}F$ has a nuclear spin of $1/2$.

Why is that? Is the selection rule claimed by Lubos Motl simply wrong? If so, what is the appropriate way to fill the states and calculate nuclear spin? For example, [why does $^{23}Na$ have a nuclear spin of $3/2$](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/90741/76347)?

Comment: I always thought that selection "rules" were better called selection "suggestions" - in multi-nucleon, like multi-electron, systems there are many factors at play. The 5/2 state is only 200keV above the 1/2 ground state for F19.

Comment: *Is the selection rule claimed by Lubos Motl simply wrong?* Yes, it's simply wrong. I left a comment on his answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Here](https://arxiv.org/abs/1801.02667) is a paper on the nuclear structure of this nucleus. It's not spherical, it's deformed. Basically the very first thing you should do when trying to guess the ground-state configuration of a nucleus is to try to find out whether or not it's spherical. If it's deformed, then you're not going to get the right answers by looking at a diagram of energy levels at spherical deformation. For a diagram showing the relevant energy levels in deformed nuclei of this region, see [this paper](https://arxiv.org/abs/1107.5248), p. 30. The $d5/2$ shell splits up with deformation into states with definite values of $j_z$ along the axis of symmetry. For a prolate nucleus, the lowest $j_z$ drops the fastest. When you couple this odd particle to the rotational degrees of freedom, you get a rotational band in which the lowest spin equals the single particle's value os $j_z$.